# Referencing a numpy arrray without creating an expensive copy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reference, slice

Let's say that I have a function that requires that NumPy `ndarray` with 2 axes, e.g., a data matrix of rows and columns. If a "column" is sliced from such an array, this function should also work, thus it should do some internal `X[:, np.newaxis]` for convenience. However, I don't want to create a new array object for this since this can be expensive in certain cases.

I am wondering if there is a good way to do it. For example, would the following code be safe (by that I mean, would the global arrays *always* be unchanged like Python `list`s)?

```
X1 = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
X2 = np.array([1,4,7])

def some_func(X):
    if len(X.shape) == 1:
        X = X[:, np.newaxis]
    return X[:,0].sum()       

some_func(X2)
some_func(X1[:, 0])
some_func(X1)
```

I am asking because I heard that NumPy arrays are sometimes copied in certain cases, however, I can't find a good resource about this. Any ideas?

Comment: Any particular reason you are going for `[:,np.newaxis]`? Would it be okay if it is `X = X[np.newaxis]` instead, i.e. it keeps it as 2D array of shape `1 x N` when the input is a 1D array?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention it, but I would like to have an `Nx1` dimensional array.

Comment: The beautiful thing about NumPy is that ndarrays, unlike lists, do not make copies during slicing operations. You get a lightweight wrapper. But that also means you can influence your master-array by changing the slice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It shouldn't create a copy. For illustration:

```
>>> A = np.ones((50000000,))
>>> B = A[:,np.newaxis]
>>> B.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

Note the `OWNDATA : False` - it's sharing data with A.

For a few more details have a look at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html. The basic rule is that it doesn't create a copy unless you're doing indexing with either an array of indices (e.g. `A[[1,2,4]]`) or with a boolean array (e.g. `A[[True, False, True]]`). Pretty much everything else returns a view with no copy.

Comment: I'm almost positive a new   continuous block of memory is allocated in the c code of numpy( it may or may not get garbage collected upon return)... it should be fairly easy to verify with a memory profiler ... I only know this because I just had to battle with this a day or two ago

Comment: @JoranBeasley Atleast according to the documentation "All arrays generated by basic slicing are always views of the original array" (with `np.newaxis` listed under basic slicing). I'd be happy to be corrected if the  code does something different though!

Comment: well I can guarantee I was getting a memory error on `a = a[::,columns]` for a win32 application that couldnt allocate 30mb of contiguous memory (as I said it may be garbage collected as soon as it gets out of C land) but that is perhaps not the OP's concern

Comment: Possibly depends what columns was - if it was a list of indices I think that's expected. If it was a slice then its a bit more surprising.

Comment: @JoranBeasley If you can track down the details of your case, it would make for a nice [bug report to numpy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues). It ceratinly doesn't have to allocate any memory, so if it does, we should try to get it fixed.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't create a copy - these types of operations are all just views - a copy with changed metadata of the ndarray, but not the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can reshape the input array to force it to be a `M x N` dimensional array, where `M` is the number of elements for the first dimension. Then, slice it to get the first column and sum all its elements. The reshaping and slicing must not
make copies.

So, you could have this alternative approach without the IF statement -

```
def some_func2(X):
    return X.reshape(X.shape[0],-1)[:,0].sum()
```

To check and confirm that it doesn't create a copy with reshaping and slicing, you can use `np.may_share_memory` like so -

```
In [515]: X1
Out[515]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])

In [516]: np.may_share_memory(X1,X1.reshape(X1.shape[0],-1)[:,0])
Out[516]: True

In [517]: X2
Out[517]: array([1, 4, 7])

In [518]: np.may_share_memory(X2,X2.reshape(X2.shape[0],-1)[:,0])
Out[518]: True
```

A `True` value with `np.may_share_memory` is a *good* indicator that they are views and not copies.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about `np.may_share_memory` and I have a few scenarios where this good be incredibly useful for testing. I like the `X.reshape(X.shape[0],-1)` instead of the `if` + `X[:, np.newaxis]`